# Are United States Payroll taxes refunded?

Tags: united-states, payroll-taxes, refund

Many US taxpayers have their withholdings refunded. But do refunds include payroll taxes?

I found [this page with the actual code](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/6413), but frankly, it's hopelessly unintelligible enough that I'm still not sure. I'd love a plain English answer.

If you're feeling *really* generous, what does the refund actually consist of? Which taxes are refunded, and in what percentages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Payroll taxes are taxes on the employer, not on the employee. They're not refunded unless there was a mistake of some kind, and if they are - they're refunded to the employer.

Refund on your 1040 consists of overpaid *income* taxes, which are taxes that *you* pay based on *your* **income**. That also include overpayment of social security (employee portion), credits for foreign taxes paid on the same income (to the extent they're allowable) and other credits (some may be refundable even if you don't owe any taxes, others only reduce the amount of taxes owed), etc. There are no percentages. You're refunded what you paid in excess of *your* liability, nothing more and nothing less.

Comment: Isn't payroll tax slang for FICA withholding? And that's paid by both emoter and employee. There's an employee refund if you work two jobs and have more than the annual cap withheld.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer No, not at all. FICA withholding is *not* payroll tax, its a tax on the employee and is essentially an *income* tax. Part of it may be overpaid and thus refunded (the part I mentioned as SS overpayment). See here for details: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/29091/how-does-the-social-security-wage-base-apply-to-employers/29100#29100

Comment: @Joe examples for *payroll* taxes - FICA employer portion (Subchapter B), FUTA, State unemployment, Workers' compensation, etc etc.

Comment: @littleadv: That may be what payroll tax actually *is*, but I agree with JoeTaxpayer that the term "payroll tax" is often used informally to refer to both parts of the FICA.

Comment: @Bren well I did mention that portion in my answer.

Comment: So @littleadv, what you're saying is that every employee, regardless of income bracket, is guaranteed to pay the %7.63 (or whatever) of their wages, and that only amounts accidentally paid over that are refunded?

Comment: @blaineh no, there's a cap on the SS part of FICA from employee's wages. Medicare - yes, you're going to pay medicare tax from all your wages.

Comment: @littleadv, what are the respective percentages?

Comment: @blaineh simple googe: http://www.ssa.gov/oact/progdata/taxRates.html